# Drive or campervan on the Californian coast?

Tags: california, campers

My Fiance and myself will be visiting California for 3 weeks in July 2017 for our honeymoon.

We will be driving down the coast from San Francisco to San Diego in 2-3 weeks.

Would you hire a campervan and stay where you please? If so are there good places to park up?

Or would you get a car and stay in hotels/ b&bs.
In that case can you name some guesthouses on the route, fit for a honeymoon, but not too extravagant?

Comment: Too broad, primarily opinion-based, asking to construct a tour. All of these are close-reasons for us. Please see http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It's all just McDonalds and wine-themed tourist stops!  :)  No worry about where you stop, just enjoy the scenery.  Road trip!

Comment: My old running mate Grant MacNaughton operates a Fish & Chips restaurant in Santa Barbara, http://www.macssb.com/  It's an absolute MUST.

Comment: Please note that if you take the scenic route (Highway 1) down the coast, it is a difficult drive for camper vans—narrow with hills and curves.